# Add-on menu does not appear

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gsuite-addons

After installing published Google Sheets add-on I can't see it under Add-on menu.

I checked "Run / Test as add-on" - the onOpen trigger works and menu appears.

I do not see entries for this point in time in the GCP "Operations Logging", although in Google Apps Script "My execution" status is Completed.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Send', 'CreateEvents')
      .addItem('Show', 'showEvents')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Delete Events')
      .addItem('Delete', 'deleteEvents'))
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Scopes: 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Tell me please is there some kind of error in the trigger code or do I need to open a ticket to Support team?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that the issue you are encountering might be a bug.

What you can do in this case is to **star** the issue on **Issue Tracker** [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147016387) by clicking the **★** next to the issue number and post a comment as well saying that you are affected by the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, I even sent a [bug-report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150397848).